# Using PushState/PopState to keep div content when navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I was learning some about this html5 concept and i was trying to integrated in my project .
I have a page called `chat_wnd.aspx` wish is a chat page between two client programmed by Signalr, and a masterpage having a div like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenChatwnd() {
    $("#ifrm").attr("src", "/chat_wnd.aspx");
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:OpenChatwnd();">Open chat wnd</a>
<div id="dv_chat">
    <iframe id="ifrm"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there any way to use the `push/pop state` to prevent the iframe from reloading inside the div every time i navigate to another page in my website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PushState only changes URL and adds the URL into history without change content, so you should use ajax to change your content.

Note that if you want to use `<a>` to navigate another page, your javascript may like below:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of navigating to another page

    // ajax load data
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: "GET",
        success: function(html){
            $('#content').(html);
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
            console.error(xhr.status); 
            console.error(thrownError); 
        }
    });

    // change the current URL
    window.history.pushState('', document.title, $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Also, here is a jQuery plugin [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) provides the integration of AJAX and pushState, you can see there demo at [here](http://userbag.co.uk/demo/pjax/).